# Matplot Image is squeezed Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert a matlab code to python. Here is python code i write

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib as nm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 1000;     # time points
M =   20;     # channels
nTrials = 50; # number of trials
t = np.linspace(0,6*np.pi,N);
img=(nm.repmat(np.sin(t),M,1))
plt.imshow(img);
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The output is as follows

[image: python output]

MATLAB Code

```
N = 1000;     % time points
M =   20;     % channels
nTrials = 50; % number of trials

% time vector (radian units)
t = linspace(0,6*pi,N);
img=repmat( sin(t),M,1 )
imagesc(img)
```

The output in matlab is as follows
[image: matlab output]

Alternatively i try to do the same on easy sample data
MATLAB

```
C = [0 2 4 6; 8 10 12 14; 16 18 20 22];
imagesc(C)
colorbar
```

PYTHON

```
C =np.array([0, 2 ,4 ,6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22])
C=np.reshape(C,(3,4))
plt.imshow(C);
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The image output in both is same
[image: sample data image]

I am not getting why in sin wave the image is squeezed

Comment: It is not that the sine wave is squeezed. It is because matlab automatically scale x and y dimension. Your x dim is of size 1000 which is too large compared with y=20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab automatically scales the y axis to match with x. That is why you see a near squared image even though the x range is 50x larger than the y range.

To achieve the similar effect on matplotlib, try to set the y range similar to x e.g. set M=800.
[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to change M you can still scale the y range using matplotlib:

```
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]
Note the range of the y axis remains intact in this case.